# Django urls: match '^$' and '^page/\d+)/$' in one urlpatterns

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a view:

```
index(request,page=1)
```

For now, I use this to match both "" and "page/\d+" to views.index:

```
url(r'^$', views.index)
url(r'^page/(?P<page>\d+)/$', views.index)
```

There are many views need to match both "" and "page/\d+", I wonder if there is an easy way to match this two kinds of urls.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following url.

```
url(r'^$|^page/(?P<page>\d+)/$', views.index)
```

But you have to change view function as follow:

```
def index(request, page):
    if page is None:
        page = 1
    ...
```

**NOTE**:
This adds a complexity in the urlpatterns which you will likely forget because it makes it harder to debug and read.

Comment: +1 for this but I would like to add that this adds a complexity in his urlpatterns which OP will likely forget because it makes it harder to debug and read. But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: @limelights, I agree with you. I added your comment to my answer. Thanks.